How to prevent balls peaking out of the slab when using a particle system to randomly distribute them?
How to prevent balls peaking out of the slab when using a particle system to randomly distribute them?
I am using emit from the volume, but I have some balls that are coming out of the volume. I tried Size Deflect, but it is not working.


Hello, you'll need to cheat and create an invisible emitter volume for the particles that will be slightly smaller than the object you want to show
